# What is the best statistical test to check if a sample performs better?

Tags: statistics

If we have two sample test of the time of two runners like for example:

```
runA <- sample(10:20,20,replace=T)
runB <- sample(10:20,20,replace=T)
runA
 [1] 15 16 15 15 10 20 13 18 14 10 13 14 17 13 16 15 20 11 11 19
runB
 [1] 18 11 13 10 20 19 16 14 11 20 11 14 12 12 12 20 16 20 15 20
```

Doing a t.test (in R) will tell us that if the means as significantly different

```
t.test(runA, runB)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  runA and runB
t = -0.42159, df = 36.701, p-value = 0.6758
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.613352  1.713352
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
    14.75     15.20
```

It appears that yes, they are significantly similar as the p.value is quite high. But could we say that y performed better because the mean of runB (y) is higher?

What statistical test is best to use to clearly illustrate that one sample performed better than the other?

Thanks

Comment: Long story short: you can't say that. There is no evidence supporting a significant "over performance" whatsoever only evidence that you're seeing a statistical fluke. Also "significantly similar" is **not quantified** by how large the p-value is!

Comment: What do you mean by statistical fluke? I'm using here just a sample of 20 values, but the sample could be much higher. What should I use instead. Can I blankly use the means and say y performed better. Is there any other statistical test and output that would tell me that x is performing better than x?

Comment: what you're doing (the last sentence) is exactly what Statistics is **not** about, we can't give you a test such that you can massage your data into producing the conclusion that **you** want. What you can do:
(a) from what you currently have, nothing
(b) if you still think that you expect an effect, redo the experiment with new data and 
(c) check the test again. What I meant by statistical  fluke is that the difference you're currently seeing most likely reflects random variations in your observations and does not represent any actual tangible (**reproducible**) effect.

Comment: and you can definitely not just use the means and say y performed better!

Comment: Sorry to insist and excuse my level of knowledge on statistics. 
Let’s say that you have a race with two runners. One takes 20 min and the other 15 min. We can clearly identify who performed better. So far so good. 
If I capture the performance of this two runners over multiple days (I used a random sample as an example). I can redo the experiment if necessary (if this is what you mean to ensure that the test is right). But, what statistical test will tell me who is performing better?

Comment: So let's say that on day 1 it's [20, 15], on day 2 its [18, 17], on day 3 its [15,25], on day 4 it's [16,17] etc... then you could represent the performance of runner 1 as say $17\pm 3$  with the interval containing 95% of the times. For runner 2, maybe $16\pm 5$ again with 95% of the times of the runner, so the difference in times would be $1\pm 2$ which contains $0$. In other words, there is too much variance around your measurements to say that one runner significantly outperformed the other one. I suggest you read http://www.stat.ualberta.ca/~hooper/teaching/misc/Pvalue.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure what to take from the link. "P > 0.10 = No evidence against the null hypothesis. The data appear to be consistent with the null hypothesis". Is this what stated in the initial example +/-? Maybe mentioning the p.value initially was a mistake. Is there another metric to use? What if there is no much variance, or should variance be a factor. Should I use R^2?

Comment: yes that's absolutely what's in the example. There are other metrics to compute other things, if you want a measure of statistical significance then P Value or Bayes factor. It seems like something is staying unclear: if you draw values from the same distribution and take the means, they *will* be different but not statistically so! no matter what metric you're looking at you don't want to say "oh they are different", you want to say "it looks like it's the same distribution" and that's that!

Comment: I don't think I can add much more here but maybe this: https://xkcd.com/882/

Comment: but you are referring if you draw values from the same distribution. These are values captured from independent individuals. Can we say that one performs better over the other, or is it the case to say then 'it looks like A is performing better'?

Comment: you can't say that! no matter how you turn it! (I'm going to stop here because it looks like I'm unclear, maybe someone else will explain it better)

Answer (score 1):

The point of a test such as a t-test is to determine whether the difference you see is statistically significant. Or more accurately, it's trying to tell you how likely it is you would see a result at least as big as the one in your data, under a situation where there is no *actual* difference between the two.

For example, let's say I have two coins, and I flip each of them 10 times. If one shows 5 heads and the other 6, is that difference just due to chance or are the coins really flipping differently? With so few flips, it's probably just chance, and the t-test would bear that out. Whereas if I flipped them 100 times each, and got 50 and 60 heads respectively, then the evidence starts to lean towards there being a difference in the coins.

So in your case, the t-test is saying that there is insufficient evidence to suggest a difference in the two samples. It doesn't mean that there *is* no difference, but if there is then you haven't got enough data to prove it.

Comment: Good careful & useful answer, +1

Comment: My question is, (and if we had more data) would the t.test help us to find out which runner performed better that the other or is there a better test to use?

Comment: Yes, if there actually is a true difference between the two runners, then with enough data the t-test is a suitable test to confirm that.